# How do I make a loop with a timer in canvas in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas

This is the part of my code where I need it, but I don't know how to make it infinite times, how do I add the loop?
I need to have a rectangle, and when I load the page it should appear in a random position in the canvas, and every 5 seconds a new rectangle should appear in a new position, the rectangles are always the same size

```
function rectangle(x,y){
    var ctx
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(20, 20, 15, 10);
    ctx.stroke();
    }
 function randomMove(){
    var myVar;
    var x;
    var y;
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    myVar = setInterval( ()=> {rectangle(x,y)}, 5000); // pass the rectangle function
    }
```

Comment: Generate the random numbers inside the interval, not outside, else they'll always be the same `x` and `y`

Comment: add code snippet with your html, it will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to call your `randomMove` function recursively; This way, you will generate that infinite loop which will render new rectangles each 5 seconds:

```js
function randomMove() {
  const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

  rectangle(x,y); // Define rectangle

  setTimeout(() => {
    randomMove() // Wait 5s before iterating recursively
  }, 5000)
}
```

Also, in case you want to remove your previous rectangle before drawing the new one, you will need to:

1. Define your canvas context (ctx) outside your `rectangle` function, so you can access it inside `randomMove` directly
2. Define this bit just before calling your `rectangle` function to clear the previous drawing:

```js
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Did you meant setTimeout instead of setInterval?

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 150;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

setInterval(drawRect, 500, ctx);

function drawRect(ctx) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctx.canvas.width) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctx.canvas.height) + 1;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 15, 10);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```